# Padding-top affect on other class in div

Tags: html, css, padding

if i add padding-top: 5px on .nav-list class, why this affect the padding-top on .social-list too? And how it could be avoided? i want only padding-top for .nav-list.

```css
html, body, ul, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, img, p {

 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 color:#777;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;

}

body {
 font-size:14px;
 letter-spacing: 0.2px;
}
/* --main nav--*/
nav {
 background-color: #dadada;
 height:40px;
}
.nav-list, .social-list {
 list-style: none;
}

.nav-list li a {
 color:white;
 text-decoration: none;

}
.nav-list li, .social-list li {
 float:left;;
}
.social-list {float:right;}
.nav-list {
  padding-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container">
   <ul class="nav-list">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="social-list">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/youtube.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/youtube.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/youtube.png"></a></li>
  </div>
 </nav>
```

[please see code at row 38 in css(jsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/26qts2kr/7/)

Comment: you just need nav-list{padding:12px;float:left;}

Comment: **"Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code"** does not mean you should format the link as code. It means YOU MUST INCLUDE THE CODEZ IN THE QUESTION ITSELF. Stack Overflow is not your personal debugger. We're trying to build a repository of good Q&As that will help people in the future. The absence of relevant code in your question makes it much less useful for the future (and that link will die at some point, which makes it useless too).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to apply `float:left` to `.nav-list`, and then add padding to it. Like this:

```
.nav-list {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dLg3nwbt/)